# fsck finds Multiply-claimed block(s) and files are shared with badblock inode #1

Tags: unix, inode, fsck

I have an LVM hard drive. It holds all my media for use by Kodi. It occasionally (about once a week) cannot access the media. Attempting to remount the device with `sudo mount -a` resulted in Input/Output error.

The solution from various sources was that it contains badblocks so I have run `fsck -cc /dev/icybox/media` to do a non-destructive read-write badblocks check.

It took 5 days but finally it finished, good news, no read or write errors but a couple of hundred corrupted blocks.
Here is some of the output:

```
# fsck -cc -V /dev/icybox/media
fsck from util-linux 2.34
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /mnt/icybox] fsck.ext4 -cc /dev/mapper/icybox-media
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Checking for bad blocks (non-destructive read-write test)
Testing with random pattern: done
/dev/mapper/icybox-media: Updating bad block inode.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes

Running additional passes to resolve blocks claimed by more than one inode...
Pass 1B: Rescanning for multiply-claimed blocks
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 55640069: 849596509
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 55640261: 448514694
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 55641058: 465144485
Multiply-claimed block(s) in inode 55641147: 470406248
...and lots more Multiply-claimed block(s)
```

Then this:

```
Pass 1C: Scanning directories for inodes with multiply-claimed blocks
Pass 1D: Reconciling multiply-claimed blocks
(There are 190 inodes containing multiply-claimed blocks.)

File /TV Shows/Arrested Development/Arrested Development - Season 1/Arrested Development - 119 - Best Man for the Gob.mkv (inode #55640069, mod time Sat May  5 11:19:03 2018)
  has 1 multiply-claimed block(s), shared with 1 file(s):
        <The bad blocks inode> (inode #1, mod time Thu May 20 22:36:40 2021)
Clone multiply-claimed blocks<y>? yes
```

There are a bunch more files saying they have 1 multiply-claimed blocks shared with 1 file on inode #1. Should I say yes to the clone question?

All the files shown are shared with bad block inode #1, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198673/why-does-have-the-inode-2 inode#1 stores the badblocks.

So I have a bunch of question:

1. How can this file be shared with badblocks?
2. Is the badblocks list incorrect/corrupted?
3. Is there a way to clear the badblocks list and do another scan to start over to fill it correctly?

I am not too bothered about losing the data of individual media files so long as I can take a list to re-download them.

P.S. Not sure if it is relevant, I had run the same fsck command before this and it was interrupted by a power outage so I don't know if that would cause a corrupted badblock inode #1.
I ran it another time which got to about 70% and then something went wrong and every block was becoming a read error (I think it became Input/Output error again)  so I am worried all those blocks were listed as badblocks, I cancelled the process when I noticed it at about 70% so it didn't finish.

Thanks for any help and answers

Comment: Greetings, but SO is for programming questions,  Linux or sysadmin sites would be better for this question.